# Wait(), Notify(), timers and Jbuttons

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, sleep, wait

I'm not sure how to even approach this but after doing some reading and a lot of attempts (failures) I've decided to ask the community for help. I have form A which opens and asks the user to enter a time to delay Form B from opening.  Currently I am using `sleep()` to do this but now I would like to insert another dialog box to allow the user to interrupt the timer and bring up Form B before the timer runs out.  I believe the correct way to do this is with `wait()` and `notify()` but I cannot seem to wrap my head around the numerous examples of producer and consumer models.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for a delayed task.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

A perfect job for `javax.swing.Timer`. Refer to [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for details. Here's an example to guide you in the right direction.

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TimerDemo extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private Timer timer;
    private JButton jbDoSomethingDelayed;
    private JButton jbDoItImmediately;

    public TimerDemo() {        
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Timer demo");

        jbDoSomethingDelayed = new JButton("Do something with a delay");
        jbDoItImmediately = new JButton("Do it. Do it NOW!");

        add(jbDoSomethingDelayed);
        add(jbDoItImmediately);

        jbDoItImmediately.setEnabled(false);

        timer = new Timer(0, this); // we override delay later
        timer.setRepeats(false); // we don't want it firing repeatedly

        jbDoSomethingDelayed.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String msg = "Enter delay and confirm dialog";
                JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(5, 1, 10, 1));
                Object[] content = new Object[] {msg, spinner};
                int showConfirmDialog = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(TimerDemo.this, content, "Choose", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
                if (showConfirmDialog == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                    // the important part
                    timer.setInitialDelay(((Integer)spinner.getValue()) * 1000);                    
                    jbDoSomethingDelayed.setEnabled(false);
                    jbDoItImmediately.setEnabled(true);
                    timer.start();
                }
            }
        });

        jbDoItImmediately.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                timer.stop();
                onTimerTimeout();
            }
        });

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // called by timer on EDT, no worries here
        onTimerTimeout();
    }

    private void onTimerTimeout() {   
        jbDoSomethingDelayed.setEnabled(true);
        jbDoItImmediately.setEnabled(false);
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "You've done it now. No, really...", "It is done", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                TimerDemo demo = new TimerDemo();
                demo.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be in doing something like this

```
Thread a = new Thread(new Runnable(){
   public void run(){
      //do whatever display
      try{
        Thread.sleep(timeToShowBform);
      }
      catch(InterruptedException ex){
         //interrupted.
      }finally{
      //show form B
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)

   }
});

class BRunnable implements Runnable{
public void run(){
 //if clicked, then this runnable is called.
 a.interrupt();
}
}
```

The thread `a` suppose is blocked at `sleep`, then on calling `a.interrupt()` it wakes `a`.

Comment: That would show the form outside the EDT which is probably not a good idea.

Comment: @assylias Yes, that is why I have used `Thread` above for `a` instead of only runnable.

Comment: What I'm saying is that the `finally` block will be executed on that thread, not on the EDT. And you should only interact with the GUI from the EDT.